# XML File had a node called System, this is being confused in code for the namespace System

Tags: c#, xml

This is my third attempt at writing C# code, and very little other experience. I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

I have an XML file that I used XSD.EXE on and created a class for my C# project. When I imported it I have many compile errors associated with the primary XML node being named "System", being confused with the System namespace. Is there a way around this problem?

'''

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.8.3928.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
```

[IDE view of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXhyn.png)
[New Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxSKu.png)

Comment: You are missing the namespace.  Create a new project and put the xsd generated class where the other classes are located inside a namespace.

Comment: Hi jdweng, Thank your for helping me! I think I did as you said, I started a new project and named it XML_Test, I then added a folder to the project called XML_Test, and I regenerated my Class with XSD with the namespace XML_Test. I put that file in the XML_Test folder. I attached an New Code Picture with a screen grab of my project. It appears that I still have the problem. I may have done Something wrong.   Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: All the "USING" statements have to be at the top of the module before the namespace.  So you have to move to the top "using System.Xml.Serialization" to the top of module where the other using statements are located.

Comment: Hi jdweng Thanks for that advice, that fixed one of the errors. My concern is the other over 100 that are being caused by my XML element being named system. Is there a way to tell  it system is the XML node, not the system namespace? As you can see XSD generated a class called system, that is a direct conflict. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: It is not being confused.  It is XML_Test.System while the Net Library is just System.

Comment: I did an experiment and changed an XML file from system to systema, when i regenerated the class all the errors I have are gone. I know that is the problem, what I don't know is how to fix it?

Comment: How many place did you make the change?  What it only one line : public partial class System?  The all you need to do is add an attribute above the line [XmlRoot("System")] which will then allow the XML file that has the tag System recognize the class SystemA,